# Не могу нормально вывести массив String

Tags: java

Вот у меня есть сторка prodaja и bidPrice  там хранятся значения с плавающей точкой, я хочу вывести их на экран в столбец но не получается.Думал переобразовать в масив и масив вывести но не могу, может есть способо безе переобразования в масив?

Выводит:

```
null28.109 32.681 0.434 37.427 28.626 7.630 0.251 21.685 20.300 4.370 3.440 3.150 1.297 0.103
```

А я хочу что бы он выводил без null и всё вывести в столбец то есть:

```
28.109
32.861
0.434 
.....
```

Никак не могу с этим исправится, подскажите что сделать

```
 for (Element line : allLines) {
    //String currency = line.select("").text();
    String bidPrice = line.select("td[data-rate-type=bid]").text();
    String prodaja  = line.select("td[data-rate-type=ask]").text();
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++ ){
        a[i]+=prodaja+" ";
    }}

for (int i = 0;i<1;i++){
    System.out.println(a[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> хочу ... без null

Инициализируйте элементы массива пустыми строками.

> и всё вывести в столбец

```
a[i] += prodaja + "\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @CR7 На здоровье. Успехов!